# How to get nano to work properly under mutt?

Tags: email, mutt, nano

I have set nano as the default editor in mutt; mutt launches nano normally enough, but when I try to send the message (ie. save and quit, separately) mutt says the message has been aborted. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I have no problems on Arch Linux , i tried to set `set editor=/usr/bin/nano` , and it works for me. Just onething , did you pressed ^O to save it ?

Comment: @warl0ck Yes, I did.